# AJAX multiple search boxes not merging with array merge

Tags: wp-query, ajax, search

this is a very frustrating problem.

I have some search boxes for different feilds on my site. some are acf meta fields, another is for title, and another for a keyword taxonomy.

But on the front end, only the first input box works (for title).

If i use each query individually, it works fine. I am not clear why the merge is not working. I can add in more parameters into a single query, but for some reason using an array after the 's' => $title_q breaks it!

In the ideal world, it would be best to have it all in one query, but I am struggling to see how to accomplish that.

any help is appreciated!

here is the input HTML:

```
<!-- select report title -->
        <div class="dropdowndiv"> 
            <label for ="Title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="s" id="title" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetch();">
        </div>

<!-- select report author -->

        <div class="dropdowndiv"> 
            <label for ="Title">Author:</label>
        <input type="text" name="t" id="author" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetch();">
        </div>

<!-- select report keyword -->

        <div class="dropdowndiv"> 
            <label for ="Title">Keywords:</label>
        <input type="text" name="q" id="keywords" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetch();">
        </div>

<!-- select report year of publication -->   

        <div class="dropdowndiv"> 
            <label for ="Title">Year Of Publication:</label>
        <input type="text" name="r" id="year" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetch();">
        </div>
```

and the AJAX code:

```
function fetch(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 
        action: 'data_fetch', 
        keywords: jQuery('#keywords').val(),
        author: jQuery('#author').val(),
        title: jQuery('#title').val(),
        year: jQuery('#year').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
```

and finally the output PHP and queries:

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');

function data_fetch(){

    extract($_POST);
    $author_q = $_POST["author"];
    $title_q = $_POST["title"];
    $keywords_q = $_POST["keywords"];
    $year_q = $_POST["year"];

echo "search terms in php";
echo "<br/>";
echo $keywords_q;
echo "<br/>";
echo $title_q;
echo "<br/>";
echo $author_q;
echo "<br/>";
echo $year_q;
echo "<br/>";

   $q1 = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' =>  'Library', 
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        's' => $title_q, 
        'meta_key' => 'author',
        'meta_value' => $author,
            ));

   $q2 = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' =>  'Library',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'fields'  => 'ids',
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
       'key' => 'author',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'value' => $author_q,          
                ),
            array(
       'key' => 'year-of-publication',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'value' => $year_q,
                )
        ),
    )
    );
   $q3 = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' =>  'Library',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'keywords',
             'field'  => 'slug',
            'terms' => $keywords_q,
         )
        )
    )
   );

$post_ids = array_unique( array_merge( $q1->posts, $q2->posts, $q3->posts ), SORT_REGULAR );
//$result = new WP_Query($q3);
var_dump($post_ids);
$wp_query_merged =  new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'Library',
    'post__in'  => $post_ids, 
    'orderby'   => 'date', 
    'order'     => 'DESC',
));
            while ( $q1->have_posts() ) : $q1->the_post(); ?>

            <p><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></p>

        <?php endwhile;
       echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();  

    die();
}
```

Comment: this is super dangerous to do: `extract($_POST);` you should remove it immediately for the security of your site, anybody can overwrite any variable in WP by including it in the `POST` request

Comment: Also please edit your Q to fix the broken indenting so it's more readable, and can you explain what you meant by _"using an array after the 's' => $title_q breaks it!"_? It doesn't make sense! And what did you mean by break? Can you be more specific? HTTP 500? Incorrect posts? Missing posts? PHP error message?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I'm at work and very busy so this was done quickly. Point taken on the extract post, and what I meant by breaking things was adding meta query after the 's' directive. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I understand that's what's causing it to break for you, but break is a very ambiguous term that could mean a lot of things, _how_ did it break? What is the nature of the broken-ness? Please be specific! and by adding the meta query, I don't see any array based meta queries after an `'s'` in your code, can you make sure your question contains the code that is broken so that it's clear? Don't describe it, show it! _Use the edit link underneath your questions tags to update the code_

Comment: HI Tom, i got this working in the end, the issue was with the actual data- and when I said break, i realise it was ambigous. I have also removed extract(_$post) as you suggested. in this context it was there to just pull in everything so I could be sure it was all there. What I have since discovered is that taxonomy queries, if NULL or not set, cause the query to fail, whereas meta queries do not. I reconstsucted my query using isset and everything works! job done. thanks.

Comment: can you post that as an answer rather than a comment?